# how to POST data to a remote server with javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, post

I have this code on javascript,

```
var path = 'remote site action.php';
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("method", 'POST');
form.setAttribute("action", path);
var code = "some info";

        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "data");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", code);

        form.appendChild(hiddenField);
        document.body.appendChild(form);

 form.submit();
```

Unfortunately I can't post it to remote server. The code does its job but When I execute it, the remote page says access denied. (you do not have permission) (remote server/action.php). Should I change the permission param of the remote page?...any suggestions?

Comment: Is this script running on a page that is on the same domain?

Comment: Request using -  `XMLHttpRequest`  or jQuery.

Comment: Thanks all for response..there are two different domains...however I figured that for some reason one server has restriction over post while with other server I can execute the script successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting a 403 Access denied, then the problem is that the server doesn't want anyone to see that page. If it's your server, then try changing the permissions settings for that page. Cross domain shouldn't be a problem if you're submitting an HTML form.

Comment: it is 403. But the hosting page is mine..I have two hosting site..I want to pass the data from my pc to one of the server. What permission should that page have to post data..like 777 or anything?

Comment: To post data to that page, you need to make sure that the page is public.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your server could have authentication turned on.  Do you have basic auth enabled?  Are you allowed to POST to your server or can you only use GET?  Are you submitting cross domain?  There's a lot of possible scenarios that could be causing this so you'll need to identify the most likely cause and go from there.  If the javascript is posting to your server than the problem is not with the JS, but rather with your server.

Answer (score -1):

1.See on you address bar at browser. URL of this script should be begin with http://
   **AND not** with C:\  or file:// (always happen if your script are save as .html and you run it by clicking)

2.see domain of your script.It should be same with your server/action.php